# Extraer valor de una etiqueta HTML con PHP

Tags: php, html

Necesito saber si mediante **explode** o **substr** puedo obtener los valores entre las etiquetas **span** del siguiente código bucle. Cuál sería la sintaxis apropiada? GRACIAS!

Edito: todo el cómputo HTML es un campo obtenido de la bbdd

```
    <div id="grupo"><span>5</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 1</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>
    <div id="grupo"><span>6</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 2</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>
    <div id="grupo"><span>7</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 3</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>
```

Comment: Más allá de que no deberías usar funciones de string y usar DOM, ¡¿tres divs con el mismo id?!

Comment: sí, es irrelevante, es para ponerlo aquí pero les incluyo un contador i++

Comment: Hola @rafa_pe no te mates la cabeza al parecer lo que necesitas puede ser un poco complicado ya que principalmente uno trabaja con php para el manejo de formularios, te recomiendo que busques otra alternativa de poder obtener ese valor, una alternativa puede ser que uses id en medios del span trabajes con javascript para enviarle los valores a php  pero lo dudo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que traes un `string` *independiente* por lo qué dices:

> ...obtener los valores entre las etiquetas span del siguiente código bucle...
>
> todo el cómputo HTML es un campo obtenido de la bbdd

Tendrías dos soluciones tanto con el `explode` como con el `substr` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 

$HTML = array(
    '<div id="grupo"><span>5</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 1</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
    '<div id="grupo"><span>6</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 2</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
    '<div id="grupo"><span>7</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 3</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
    );

foreach($HTML as $element){
    $explode = explode("</span>", $element);
    $value = $explode[0];
    echo $value . "<br />";
}

echo "<hr />";

foreach($HTML as $element){
    echo substr($element, 0, 33);
}

?>
```

El cual mostraría un resultado más o menos como este (los valores correspondientes dentro de la etiqueta `<span>`):

5
6
7

---

5

6

7

Comment: Brillante. Muchas gracias!!